# powerthesaurus-api getting empty array as output

Tags: jquery, node.js, thesaurus

[image][image]I am referred the below link to use of Powerthesaurus-api.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerthesaurus-api

When I try the sample code, no data is outputted. What setup step am I missing?

I have done the obvious npm install but when I try a sample e.g "neck pain", getting only empty array. Help me to resolve it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe missing [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for express. Add

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

as well as

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Express has added support for body-parser without installing an additional package

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
```

> In order to get access to the post data we have to use body-parser . Basically what the body-parser is which allows express to read the body and then parse that into a Json object that we can understand.

Comment: will check it , thanks @conrad Lotz

Comment: after adding bodyparser also, its same output only, Is am I missing any dependencies .?